# pandas apply list of function to data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

Lets take boston data set available in the `from sklearn.datasets import load_boston`

```
boston = load_boston()
X = pd.DataFrame(boston["data"])

           0     1      2    3      4      5      6       7     8      9     10      11     12
0     0.00632  18.0   2.31  0.0  0.538  6.575   65.2  4.0900   1.0  296.0  15.3  396.90   4.98
1     0.02731   0.0   7.07  0.0  0.469  6.421   78.9  4.9671   2.0  242.0  17.8  396.90   9.14
2     0.02729   0.0   7.07  0.0  0.469  7.185   61.1  4.9671   2.0  242.0  17.8  392.83   4.03
3     0.03237   0.0   2.18  0.0  0.458  6.998   45.8  6.0622   3.0  222.0  18.7  394.63   2.94
4     0.06905   0.0   2.18  0.0  0.458  7.147   54.2  6.0622   3.0  222.0  18.7  396.90   5.33
5     0.02985   0.0   2.18  0.0  0.458  6.430   58.7  6.0622   3.0  222.0  18.7  394.12   5.21
6     0.08829  12.5   7.87  0.0  0.524  6.012   66.6  5.5605   5.0  311.0  15.2  395.60  12.43
```

I have built a machine learning model (RF) and have obtained all estimators in the model.

`estimators = model.estimators_`

You can think this has list of functions that takes row level data and return a value.

```
>> estimators = model.estimators_
>> estimators
[DecisionTreeRegressor(criterion='mse', max_depth=60, max_features=8,
           max_leaf_nodes=None, min_impurity_decrease=0.0,
           min_impurity_split=None, min_samples_leaf=5,
           min_samples_split=12, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
           presort=False, random_state=1838148368, splitter='best'), DecisionTreeRegressor(criterion='mse', max_depth=60, max_features=8,
           max_leaf_nodes=None, min_impurity_decrease=0.0,
           min_impurity_split=None, min_samples_leaf=5,
           min_samples_split=12, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
           presort=False, random_state=1754873550, splitter='best'), DecisionTreeRegressor(criterion='mse', max_depth=60, max_features=8,
           max_leaf_nodes=None, min_impurity_decrease=0.0,....]
```

I want each estimator/function in list to be apply to every row in the data frame.

If I don't convert the data to data frame `boston['data']` returns a 2D Array. I can use two `for loops` to accomplish above. Assume X is a 2D array then I can do following

```
for x in range(len(X)):
    vals = []
    for estimator in model.estimators_:
        vals.append(estimator.predict(X[x])[0])
```

I don't want to use 2D array option because I want to keep the index information of the DataFrame for future operations.

Answer (score 2):

In the latest version of `pandas`, `df.agg` should be able to do exactly this.

Unfortunately it appears to be broken for the current version when `axis=1`: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16679

Here's a hacky way around it:

```
X.T.agg(estimators).T
```

Comment: is there away to parallelize this process, imagine the `estimators` array being 1000 and DF with 100,000 rows.

Comment: Sure, the obvious way would be to cut `estimators` into slices of a shorter length, then get the result for each slice, and merge the results together using `pd.merge` on the index.

Comment: Can you point towards to an example...? Is it buy using `map`

Comment: No... use the same code I gave you but with a slice of `estimators` each time rather than the whole of `estimators`.